# Cheat sheet for mercurial's hgrc conf file?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I wonder if there are good cheat sheets for all the options you can set in mercurial's hgrc file?

I cant find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the [manual page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) not sufficient?

Comment: the problem was to find it. how did you navigate to that page from http://mercurial.selenic.com ?

Comment: @ajsie: From the homepage, click 'Guide', then 'Tutorial in the Mercurial Wiki' (2nd paragraph). It's linked at the start of the tutorial. You can also type 'man hgrc' from a terminal if you're in Linux.